# How can I remove author and co-authors from a navigation bar in beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer

There are 6 co-authors of my presentation. How can I remove all their names from the navigation bar and leave them on the title page?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Which beamer theme are you using? You can try a different beamer theme that does not contain the author names in the navigation bar.

Comment: I am using PaloAlto. The answer below is working fine, but thanks anyway for a suggestion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably specifying the optional short author list will do the trick:

```
\author[First Author]{First Author \and Second Author \and Third Author}
```

**Edit:**
As discussed below, the suggested solution works for my setup and I would guess that it does so for most setups. More specifically, it works if the theme (or you yourself manually) uses `\insertshortauthor` to display the author list in the navigation bar (header, footer, etc.). The same goes for `\insertshorttitle` and `\insertshortdate`..

Comment: I'll vote you up once you test it. :-)

Comment: I tested it and it does work:)

Comment: Well, it works for my setup. I don't know if it will for Marcin's theme etc., but I would guess so. Hence the "probably" :-) It works if the theme (or you yourself manually) uses `\insertshortauthor` to display the author list in the navigation bar (header, footer, etc.). The same goes for `\insertshorttitle` and `\insertshortdate`..

Comment: That comment would make a great edit to your answer, whereas "probably" makes it sound like you just typed it in without testing. (but you did already get my up vote; halo effect from the green check)

Comment: @Matthew: I've amended my answer.. Sorry for being a bit vague.